# MySQL daily check and update

Tags: mysql

Is possible to create a routine or procedure that can automatic everyday check a date in a table.

To be simpler : I want to check if the date on a user have permitions to enter a site and when the date pass want to make the user field activated false.

routine daily
 check if (todaydate < dateclient) then
           client.activated= false

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the routine is simple enough, but to run it on a daily basis you'll need to wrap it in a cronjob (*nix) or Scheduled Task (Windows). The routine, unfortunately, cannot execute itself - and to the best of my knowledge MySQL server does not possess the ability to run routines at scheduled intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be a simple UPDATE query. Something like the following:

```
UPDATE Client
SET Activated = 'false'
WHERE NOW() < dateclient
```

You would obviously need to modify this for your schema and then schedule it to run daily using cron or an alternative scheduler of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the help .. I see now, there is no sql server automatic routines , the only away is using the system to execute the scripts .